# One-line text not aligned to center of div

Tags: html, css, text-align

For divs with multi-line titles the text is aligned perfectly to the center. However for single-line titles this is not the case (even with text-align set to center). The text aligns itself to the left border of the parent span. Seems absolutely trivial but have not managed to get it right.

```css
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity:0;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position:absolute;
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-content"><span>Post Title</span></span>
```

Comment: you want to align it horizontally center?

Comment: first of all if you use display: table-cell the parent must have display: table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix using your code (i changed the background color and opacity so I could see it).

Main changes were to make parent display: table and to give the child span a width of 100% so that your text-align would work.

```css
span.text-content {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position:absolute;
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-content"><span>Post Title</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#fe0c9da444a8df390c6242afa00f0bb3

It's a simple fix!

When using [display table-cell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) the parent element **must** be [display table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

**NOTE:** By default span elements are [display inline](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

To make your text centered horizontally you need to have [text-align center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) (in this case on the parent of `table-cell`.

Also in this case you don't need position (or top) applied to `table-cell` because using [vertical-align middle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) already centers your text vertically on the `table-cell`.

In addition your `span.text-content` is overqualified just use `.text-content` instead.

BTW: I removed opacity on `.text-content` so I could see the text.

```css
.text-content {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-content">
  <span>Post Title</span>
</span>
```